# how to sort the numbers with decreasing order

Tags: c, sorting

I want to write numbers into  array x[] with decreasing order. For instance I enter the lenght of the array as 3, but the numbers are not listed as 3, 2, 1. It writes 0 0 0. Can anyone advise what do I need to do ?

```
int main()
{
  int x[500000], size, i;
  printf("Enter the lenght of the array: ");
  scanf("%d", &size);

  for ( i = size; i > 0; i-- ) 
  {
    printf( "%4d", x[ i ] );
  } /* end for */
```

Comment: Did you initialize the elements of the array?

Comment: first write a pseudocode (the logic) and then implement it.

Comment: no,I did not initialize the elements of the array. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just one line added to your code will initialize at least the elements you are printing:

```
int main()
{
  int x[500000], size, i;
  printf("Enter the lenght of the array: ");
  scanf("%d", &size);

  for ( i = size; i > 0; i-- ) 
  {
    x[i] = i;   // <<<<<<<<<<<<<< add this line
    printf( "%4d", x[ i ] );
  } 
}
```

If you want all the elements to have the corresponding value in them, you can do

```
int main()
{
  int x[500000], size, i;
  printf("Enter the lenght of the array: ");
  scanf("%d", &size);

  // initialize all the elements:
  for( i = 0; i < 50000; i++) x[i] = i;

  // check just a few:
  for ( i = size; i > 0; i-- ) 
  {
    printf( "%4d", x[ i ] );
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You enter the LENGTH of the array, but this provides no informatio about element values. It is like I'm telling you: I give you 5 numbers, sort them. You can't sort them because you don't know the element values.
The values that you get are just garbage values from memory.

It is a little bit unclear what you really want to do. If you just want to get an output like 3, 2, 1, put `printf("%d ", i);` inside for loop (and get rid of array). If you really want to sort some data, then you need to get the data into an array, then implement a sorting algoritm to sort it.

Comment: I try to implement quicksort for a reverse ordered list. For instance; array size will be 1000  so number will be ordered as 1000, 999, 998...2,1.  Then quicksort will execute and sort the list as 1,2,3...,999, 100.

Comment: There is no point in sorting a reverse-ordered list. You can just iterate it from the end to the begging.